# php 8.1 avif error (docker): No codec available

Tags: php, docker, avif

I have php 8.1 via docker and avif functions not working.

**Warning: imageavif(): avif error - Could not encode image: No codec available in /var/www/test.php on line 5**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    libzip-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libavif-dev \
    libaom-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql mysqli bcmath sockets calendar gettext \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-webp --with-jpeg --with-avif --with-xpm \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure exif && docker-php-ext-install exif && docker-php-ext-enable exif \
    && pecl install xdebug-3.1.3 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

WORKDIR /var/www
```

PhpInfo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEhlY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YezSm.png)

My test.php:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

var_dump(imageavif(imagecreatetruecolor(8, 8), "/tmp/test")); // true
var_dump(file_get_contents("/tmp/test")); // empty string
die();
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the current version of `libaom` that requires you to do some setup by hand. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81217 for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrote Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions gd
```

Comment: For those that modify a WordPress Docker image or similar where GD is already there, slip in a `mv /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.x` to disable it.